# Inequality involving the fractional Laplacian

Tags: operator-theory, laplacian

In  the book  Wavelets and Operators authored by Yves Meyer and translated by D.Salinger  page  47 the author presents the following inequalities without proof:
$$
\left \| \Lambda^{s}f  \right \|_{p} \leq C(s,n) \times  \left \|  \left( I- \Delta   \right)^{ \frac{s}{2} } f\right \|_{p} 
$$

$$
\left \|  \left( I- \Delta   \right)^{ \frac{s}{2} } f\right \|_{p}  \leq C'(s,n) \times  \left \|  \left( I + \Lambda^{s}    \right) f\right \|_{p}
$$

Where $ \Delta $ is the Laplacian operator defined on $ \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $ \Lambda= \left(- \Delta \right)^{ \frac{1}{2} } $, $ s \geq 0$, $ p \geq 1 $ and $ \left \| . \right \|_{p} $ is the $ L^{p} $ norm. For convenience one might take $f$ to be in a small dense subset like $ C^{\infty}_{c} $.

P.S: For the first one the author suggests to compare Fourier transform of 
$ \Lambda^{s}f $ and $ \left( I- \Delta   \right)^{ \frac{s}{2} } f$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Have you worked against p norms before?

Comment: @mathreadler: Yes